# Which app permissions are required for the RingCentral Call Control API?

Tags: permissions, ringcentral, call-control

I'm wondering if anyone has had any success with the new RingCentral Call Control API, particularly around app permissions.

The [docs](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Account-Telephony-Sessions-Event) suggest the app needs the CallControl permission.  The problem is that this permission does not appear to exist.  Do we use the "Active Call Control" permission instead?

My use case is for creating subscriptions using the "/restapi/v1.0/account/~/telephony/sessions" event filter.  Even though the "Active Call Control" permission appears to work, I'm not convinced it's the correct approach.

When the "Active Call Control" permission is not set, I get the error "Required application permission [CallControl] is missing" on subscription creation.  When it is set, I don't get an error and the subscription appears to work.  So what's the problem?

Well, for one, I don't like the I'm just guessing at what the proper permission is.  I don't see any documentation where the app permissions are defined.

Also, when I go to graduate the app from the sandbox, it tells me that the "Active Call Control" permission was unused.  This might be a separate issue, a quirk with subscriptions, but it adds to my feeling that perhaps I shouldn't just be guessing.

Links to relevant documentation would be appreciated, as would direction or experience with this API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up. This is a bug in the documentation, the actual permission name is "Active Call Control" and not "CallControl". You are using  "Active Call Control" correctly. This permission is used for both Telephony Sessions Notifications and [Active Call Control APIs](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Control). We shall update the documentation soon.

If you want to see any changes, please feel free to send your feedback directly to our Public Developer Glip Group https://developers.ringcentral.com/community.html.